# Why does my interface keep swapping from static to DHCP?

Tags: centos, dhcp

I have set the static IP on two ethernet ports, `eno1` and `enp4s0`. I set "manual" and the IP address values, some with gateway, some with DNS values.

I use `nmtui`.

I reboot the device, and it suddenly swaps over to dynamic / DHCP.

What could cause this?

What does the "Automatically Connect" checkbox do? Does this mean that it will *try* to connect using the given settings? If it fails would it fall back to attempt DHCP?

I'm very confused about this.

Comment: The tags say CentOS, so read the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` files and see if your configuration is actually getting saved there or not. If not, are you running the `nmtui` command as root or as a regular user? Is some kind of non-default security hardening applied to the system?

Comment: @telcoM I'm running `nmtui` as root. There is some security hardening via TPM but nothing that would apply to the network, as far as I'm aware.